# Which version of Visual Studio should I install?

Tags: visual-studio

I am going to install Visual Studio. I want to know if the latest version of Visual Studio 2010 is backward compatible with previous versions like VS 2005 and 2008. Or is the code functionality and deploy-ability more dependent on the .NET framework version.
I am trying to use a code which will be built into dll. I am not sure in which version of VS the code was written(most probably VS 2005).

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to go with the latest Version.
VS 2010 can target multiple frameworks.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197.aspx
So the dll should know with which framework it was compiled...

Answer (score 1):

I have never found any issues with Visual Studio 2010 and previous versions' code. It also does feature significantly improved Intellisense and [IMHO] faster building.

Answer (score 1):

- they are all backward compatible
- 2005 and above allow you to target the framework you want when creating
  the project
- if the project is older
  than the VS, it will prompt you with
  a migration wizard upon opening
  it(this is a one time only step.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to note that i've found with 2010 which have caused us a couple of issues:

1) NHibernate (Castle Proxy) doesn't work with .net framework 4 (Currently)

2) Test Projects are always created aimed at .net framework 4, and you cannot target a lower version of the framework.

Otherwise not many problems, its also nice that the database addition of Visual Studio 2010 has intellisense on your tables/views, as well as many other changes

Answer (score 0):

Always go with the latest, now 2010